# JavaScript function called on checkbox change

Tags: javascript, checkbox

Stuck at calling a simple JS function. Developer tools at chrome, console tab, thows

> (index):591 Uncaught ReferenceError: checkbox is not defined
>       at myFunction ((index):591)
>       at HTMLInputElement.onclick

Code is

```
<span>Notificaciones</span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">         
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
              var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
              if(checkbox.checked){
                alert("suscribe");
              }  else{
                  alert("descuscribe");
              };
            };
    </script>
```

Comment: It should be checkBox.checked as that is the variable u have declared.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was a typo on checkbox and checkBox

```html
<span>Notificaciones</span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()"> 

<script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction() {
              var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
              if(checkBox.checked){
                alert("suscribe");
              }  else{
                  alert("descuscribe");
              };
            };
    </script>
```

Should work now :)

Comment: Accepted the answer by the snippet that allows to prove the example, thanks! I can not believe I was so blind to not see the typo ...

Answer (score -1):

Just typo 
"if(checkbox.checked){"
instead of "if(checkBox.checked){"

Answer (score -1):

In the if statement that you have you put `checkbox.checked` which should be `checkBox.checked`.

```
<html>
<head>
   <script type="text/javascript">
      function myFunction() 
        {
        var checkBox = document.getElementById("myCheck");
        if(checkBox.checked)
        {
          alert("suscribe");
        }  
        else
        {
          alert("descuscribe");
        };
      };
   </script>
</head>
<body>
<span>Notificaciones</span>
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheck" onclick="myFunction()">
</body>
</html>
```